# How to refresh tableau report through SSIS

Tags: ssis, tableau-api

I have a SSIS package which put data to a staging table from csv file and calls a procedure which makes certain updates in the staging table,now I want to refresh one tableau report from this SSIS package.
Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the SSIS package can call command line tasks:

https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/executing-msdos-commands-in-ssis/

Here is a method for a Tableau Extract to be refreshed via command line:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_refresh_extract_commandline.htm

Add the two together, and hopefully it will work for you.

Alternatively, if your SSIS package runs on a schedule, you could run a coinciding task with the TDE API - which can take many programatic forms:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_TDE_API.htm

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I will try the steps given by you and update you,I am new to tableau.

Comment: Any luck here? If you were able to find an answer on your own please post it and give the green check mark.

Comment: No luck so far :-(